# JQuery Colour Picker - From web.Config file

Tags: jquery

I am working in jQuery Color Picker. I am having a constant data in my web.config file.

```
<add key="colorCode" value="8A2BE2,0000FF,A52A2A,D87093,00FFFF,FFE4C4,008080,FF00FF,B8860B,FF8C00,800080,DA70D6,40E0D0"/>
```

I my aspx page, i am having the method like

```
 var colorCode = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["colorCode"]%>';
 $(function () {
 $('#color3').colorPicker({ pickerDefault: "ffffff", colors: [colorCode], transparency: true });
 });
```

The color picker is not recognising the colors which i had given in the web config file. How to fix this.

Comment: witch color picker are you using?

Comment: There are few color picker plugins exists. Could you clarify which one you are use? By the way, try to add leading sharp symbol to each defined color: `value="#8A2BE2,#0000FF,#A52A2A,#D87093,#00FFFF...`

Comment: This post is a bit different from your issue but I hope it gives yous something useful...<http://forums.asp.net/t/1349824.aspx/1> give it a try..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are passing the values like:

```
["000, 000, fff, fff"];
```

and you need

```
['000', '000', 'fff', 'fff'];
```

as showed [here](https://github.com/laktek/really-simple-color-picker).

Try adding the `''` in the config, or using split

```
"000, 000, fff, fff".split(","); //["000", " 000", " fff", " fff"]
```

In your code, the options look like this:

**1**

**Config**

```
 <add key="colorCode" value="8A2BE2,0000FF,A52A2A,D87093,00FFFF,FFE4C4,008080,FF00FF,B8860B,FF8C00,800080,DA70D6,40E0D0"/>
```

**Code**

```
var colorCode = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["colorCode"]%>';
 $(function () {
      $('#color3').colorPicker({ 
             pickerDefault: "ffffff", 
             colors: colorCode.split(","), 
             transparency: true 
      });
 });
```

**2**

**Config**

```
 <add key="colorCode" value="'8A2BE2','0000FF','A52A2A','D87093','00FFFF','FFE4C4','008080','FF00FF','B8860B','FF8C00','800080','DA70D6','40E0D0'"/>
```

**Code**

```
var colorCode = [<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["colorCode"]%>];
 $(function () {
      $('#color3').colorPicker({ 
             pickerDefault: "ffffff", 
             colors: colorCode, 
             transparency: true 
      });
 });
```

If neither of them work, try removing the `' '` in the **1** example, when getting the value from the config

Comment: For testing i had given like this..var arrCars = "['8A2BE2', '0000FF', 'A52A2A']"; ...........$('#color3').colorPicker({ pickerDefault: "ffffff", colors: [arrCars], transparency: true });...Still its not working

Comment: it should be `var arrCars = ['8A2BE2', '0000FF', 'A52A2A'];` and then `$('#color3').colorPicker({ pickerDefault: "ffffff", colors: arrCars, transparency: true });`. Take a good look to the docs :)

Comment: can i give like this in my web config file.....<add key="colorCode" value="['8A2BE2','0000FF']"...But its not getting the values from web config..

Comment: you could do that but that won't work, or either you try what I put in the answer or you try doing `<add key="colorCode" value="'8A2BE2','0000FF'">` and your first code

Comment: your code works fine, when i give the colours in aspx itself. but i need to give in web config. I want the format of config file colour codes...You had not mentioned the web.config format

Comment: Ok, last try. If you try what I've put in the answer it should work, and if you put what I've put in the comment it should work as well. I'll edit the answer to be a little bit more concise, then you'll have to try by yourself :)